# Pass numpy array to C++ using Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I am trying to pass a numpy array to C++ using Boost.Python.

The C++ code is:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

void f(boost::python::numpy::ndarray& x){}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtest)
{
  boost::python::def("f", f);
}
```

The Python code is:

```
import libtest
import numpy
x=numpy.array(range(3))
libtest.f(x)
```

This gives a segmentation fault. This happens when passing the variable by value and by reference.

I have found a way to do what I needed. However the purpose of using Boost.Python was to be able to simply call the functions from the module without having to write a wrapper on the Python side as is the case with ctypes where certain types or return values have to be dealt with.

Is is possible to simply pass a reference to a numpy array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and apparently solved it by putting

`boost::python::numpy::initialize();`

at top of my BOOST_PYHON_MODULE definition.

Comment: same for me while using *Boost 1.77.0* along with *python 2.7*